# Cannot see component name at design time

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I've constructed a new component based on an Intraweb Button(Intraweb XIV)
and installed it in a new package, regulary installed on the ide.

The component works perfectly, the only trouble is that at design time I cannot see the component name, since the component is rendered as a little gray rectangle with a Iw logo, without any name or caption.

So that if I place several buttons on a form I cannot distinguish among them.
Any suggestion ?

Some more information :

Intraweb is a framework to implement web applications.
You place components on a special "fake" form, that exists only at design time, but that does not exists at run time.
At run time the infrastructure asks every component to render itself producing the final html code.
To this purpose every component has an overridable  RenderHtml procedure that must return the html code.

What you see at design time is (probably) produced by another procedure
(the doc is rather lacking about it) that I'd like to override, but that I don't know about.

As I said, if I place on the form an original tIWButton, at design time I see a classical 3d gray button with the button caption on it.
If instead I place a NewButton I see a different darker gray flat button
with a little Iw logo on it.

This is the code of my component (something omitted).

I've created the component just to add an Image field and to render a different html code during run time, that I can customize via css.
This should have no impact on the design time appearance of the component.

Practicaly, all I would need to override should be the renderhtml function:

```
TNewButton = class(TIWButton)

  protected
    fImage           : string;

  published
    property    Image: string  read fImage write fImage;

  public
    function    RenderHTML(AContext: TIWBaseHTMLComponentContext): TIWHTMLTag; override;
  end;



function tNewButton.RenderHTML(AContext: TIWBaseHTMLComponentContext): TIWHTMLTag;
var   Elem  : tIwTextElement;
      txt   : string;
      disab : string;
begin
  if enabled then disab := '' else disab := ' disabled="disabled" ';
  txt := '<button class="newbutton" '+disab+'>';
  if fimage <> '' then
    txt := txt + '<img src="'+ fimage +'"/>';
  txt := txt + '<span class="newbutton-text">' + Caption + '</span>';
  txt := txt + '</button>';
  Elem   := tIwTextElement.Create(nil);
  elem.text := txt;
  Result := TIWHTMLTag.CreateTag('DIV');
  Result.Contents.Add (Elem);
end;
```

Comment: Use a diffrent color at designtime

Comment: Based on the fact that you claim that these components are shown as rectangles with only IW icon on them I would suggest that at design time Delphi might be considering these as nonvisual components. It would greatly help if you could show your new components code so that we might track the problem. Without the code we could only be guessing of what is wrong and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Although you say your component is based on a "Button", this sounds more like the behaviour of a non-visual component similar to (e.g.) the **TOpenDialog**.

If that is the case then the display of the component name is subject to an IDE configuration setting.  In the **Tools > Options** dialog, check the **Form Designer** settings.  Specifically the "*Show component captions*" checkbox.

If this is *OFF* then non-visual components are represented only by the component palette icon.

With this option *ON* then the component **Name** is displayed underneath the component.

**NOTE:** Even with this option off you can locate any and all components on a form using the **Structure View** of the form at design-time where the component names are displayed in a hierarchy formed by the parent/child relationships of the controls (all non-visual components are listed as "root" components since they all have the form as their parent).